# Share files across two computers in the network where one is connected via usb tethering and the other through ethernet

Tags: windows-10, router, usb, home-networking, file-sharing

I currently have 2 PC's located at diff places in the house. PC1 is connected via an ethernet cable and PC2 is connected using an usb tethered device (Phone) in the same network as PC1.

Router IP : 192.168.10.1
PC1 IP : 192.168.10.9
Phone IP : 192.168.10.3
PC2 IP : 192.168.42.55

From PC2, I can ping PC1, but the reverse is not true. Is there any way for PC1 to able to communicate or share files to PC2. Both systems are running Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This will certainly be harder than if the machines are on the same subnet. PC 2 is on subnet 42 , not 10 . That is, you cannot simply browse across different subnets, at least I have not seen that.

**Note:**  You might be wise to try to install an Ethernet cable to PC 2 or put in a Wireless Router at / near PC 1 and reachable by PC 2. Then you have proper TCP/IP networking everywhere and do not need to use your phone data plan for connectivity.

Make sure for both computers that Network Discovery, File and Print Sharing, and Password Protected sharing are all ON.

Do not try to share User folders - very secure.

Then from a command prompt on PC2:

NET USE T: \192.168.10.9\accessiblefolderonPC1

I share folders on virtual machines to host on different subnets so the above works for me very nicely.

If you get a connection error, post it back here please.

Comment: System error 67 has occurred. The network could not be found.

Comment: On PC1, set up the User Name and Password in Users and Groups.   Permit a folder on PC 1 to that User Name  (say  C:\Files).   Once done, restart PC 1 and try mapping again.    Take a look at this article as well to see if it helps:   https://windowsreport.com/system-error-67-occured/#:~:text=System%20error%2067%20is%20a%20Windows%20Server%20issue%20that%20can,to%20map%20a%20network%20drive.&text=The%20network%20name%20cannot%20be,Prompt%20displays%20that%20error%20message.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with file sharing (SMB) between hosts in different subnets, if those subnets can reach each other through a router... but I think the issue with Android tethering is that it deliberately implements a firewall so that they _don't_ necessarily have connectivity.

Comment: I amended my answer to suggest extending Ethernet or using a standard Wireless Router in range of PC 2. That will certainly make connection and sharing much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it using the following method: (Windows 10)

My IP Configuration
PC 1 IP = 192.168.42.190
PC 2 IP = 192.168.1.6

PC 1 was connected to the router through a smartphone USB tethering, while PC 2 was connected directly to the router via wifi.

First, i pinged PC 2 from PC 1 using CMD ping, which resulted in a successful ping

Then, I opened Windows Explorer from PC 1 and entered the IP address of PC 2, followed by \ in the address bar:

\192.168.1.6

Pressing enter loaded the shared folders of PC 2 on PC 1. This enables transfers between both computers. However, PC 2 failed to ping PC 1, though it was still possible to share between computers as PC 1 could read and write to folders on PC 2

However, I noticed the transfer rates were a bit slower than they usually are. I use free file sync to sync files between two computers, and I was able to successfully sync my files using this method.